# Can't override indexAction() of Magento 1.7 CartController

Tags: php, xml, magento, controller, overriding

I am trying to override default indexAction() for Mage_Checkout_CartController. I have created following files in my app/local:
MyNamespace/cartStockCheck/controllers/CartController.php
MyNamespace/cartStockCheck/etc/config.xml

And also in app/etc/modules:
MyNamespace_CartStockCheck.xml

It appears that Magento DOES pick up my extension because I can see it listed in Admin backend in advanced section but apart from that nothing happens when I open up the cart.

EDIT: No other addon overrides CartController. I have also fixed incorrect call in indexAction. Still can't see my text being echoed in cart

EDIT2: Check my answer below. It works!

Contents of CartController.php are:

```
<?php   
  require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';

  class MyNamespace_CartStockCheck_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
  {
    public function addAction()
    {
        echo 'test addAction';
        parent::addAction();
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'test indexAction';
        parent::addAction();
    }
  }
?>
```

Contents of config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyNamespace_CartStockCheck>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyNamespace_CartStockCheck>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <MyNamespace_CartStockCheck before="Mage_Checkout">MyNamespace_CartStockCheck</MyNamespace_CartStockCheck>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Contents of MyNamespace_CartStockCheck.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <MyNamespace_CartStockCheck>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
        </MyNamespace_CartStockCheck>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Try to grip for 'extends Mage_Checkout_CartController' in order to check if the controller has been already overriden.

Comment: @Paweł Duda i've just tried you extension on my local 1.7 after making the change i mentioned below it works. BTW also make sure No other extension in your installation overrides the Mage_Checkout_CartController , if it does use <depends> tag in your MyNamespace_CartStockCheck.xml

Comment: I have done everything you suggested but I still can't get it to work! I even recreated it on freshly installed Magento 1.7 and it doesn't work there either!

Comment: @PawełDuda is it still not working  ?

Comment: No, it's not. Like I said 2 comments above, I have done everything you wrote. I'm getting paranoid, changing namespace etc but it just seems pointless..

Comment: Oh it seems crazy i've just created the same module using the same code what you've shown above on my default 1.7 C.E installation and it works like a cake... So a few basic questions.  1. Have you placed your module inside app/code/local 2. Is the module enabled and can be seen under system->configuration-?advanced 3. have you tried it in a fresh install or if its not a fresh install are you sure no other module overrides this one 4. Have you flushed / disabled the cache ? 5. IS compiling disabled ?

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. Yes, 3. Yes, 4. Yes, 5. Yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not believe this. The whole reason behind my code not working was:

```
<codepool>local</codepool>
```

instead of

```
<codePool>local</codePool>
```

in MyNamespace_CartStockCheck.xml

I actually copied the code off some tutorial where "P" wasn't capitalized and I had no idea it could be this until I started checking other extensions and noticed it. Guess I'll remember this one easily.

Comment: Yes this is one of the reasons and I feel Magento team should make codePool case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct the indexAction

```
     public function indexAction()
      {
         echo 'test indexAction';
         parent::indexAction();
      }
```

You should call  **parent::indexAction();** not  **parent::addAction();**

Comment: Corrected it, although it's not the real problem. I'm supposed to see the echoed text, which I still don't. I also scanned my project for any other addons overriding CartController and nothing was found.

Comment: If you want to see echoed code you need to put an exit after your echo and check.Else do a Mage::log()

Answer (score 0):

two reasons you need to check.
1. Are you sure you have cleared your cache.

1. Make sure compiler mode is not on. As when compiler mode is on files are fetched from inc src folder and not from elsewhere.

if these two things are in place and still you find your controller action function not called then you need to check if some override done or some event/observer has hijacked your code.

Comment: 1. Cache is cleared and disabled, 2. Compiler mode is disabled, 3. I scanned code for "extends Mage_Checkout_CartController" but nothing was found 4. Why would anything hijack my code on a fresh installation? There are no external extensions